# After running a few code I want to close current tab of browser from codebehind asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Basically,What I want is when user click on the logout button, I want to close current browser tab from codebehind.
code that I have tried

```
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
     Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("logout"); 
}
```

Now let me show you that logout page which matched with route value:

### logout.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Request.Cookies["_underid"].Value != "15")
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "alert01", "closeTab();", false);
}
Request.Cookies.Clear();
Response.Cookies.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
}
```

### logout.aspx

```
function closeTab() {
debugger;
//window.close();
window.open(location, '_self').close();
```

}
But still not able to close browser window/current tab..
Its showing this,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message explain well.

It is actually due to the security issue in https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#dom-window-close

> The close() method on Window objects should, if all the following conditions are met, close the browsing context A:
>
> The corresponding browsing context A is script-closable.
>
> The responsible browsing context specified by the incumbent settings object is familiar with the browsing context A.
>
> The responsible browsing context specified by the incumbent settings object is allowed to navigate the browsing context A.
>
> A browsing context is script-closable if it is an auxiliary browsing context that was created by a script (as opposed to by an action of the user), or if it is a top-level browsing context whose session history contains only one Document.

As a consequence, you can only close a page that is opened by the script.